# how to point to a child element inside a structure

Tags: c#, pointers, structure

```
public struct TerrainProperties {
    public int currentLevel;
    public bool isHorizontal;
}

TerrainProperties terrainProperties;
```

this is my structure
i want to create a pointer to the child elements
e.g:

```
int* currentLevel = terrainProperties->currentLevel;
```

but I am receiving an error

Comment: pointers and fixed size buffers may only be used in an unsafe context, but I don't remember using them in university, and I prefer not to use them

Comment: Wait, is this actually about C++? There's no `public int` in C++. You need to say what language your question is about by using the appropriate tag. There are a hundred similar-looking curly-brace languages that are all different.

Comment: im using c# in unity3d sorry for not being so clear

Comment: Please start using tags properly. Your question would never get any attention if you don't tag it with the right language. Nobody reads *all* the questions on SO in the hope of finding one that might be about something they care about.